# How to get innertext from body of a URL

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, httprequest

I am trying to get innerText of `https://www.example.com/` in a nodejs appplication. I tried using `request` npm module to fetch body of URL as shown below:

```
function getBodyText() {
    request({
        url:'https://www.example.com/'
    }, (error, response, body) => {
        console.log(body.innerText);
    });
}
```

The above code displays body of the current page I am in (https:www.google.com). Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

In your above code, the `body` value is a just a string. `innerText` on the other hand assumes `body` is a DOM [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node).

In Node, the DOM is not present like it would be in the browser, so in order to access the DOM Nodes that were returned you'll need to load `body` using the package [Cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org). You can assign the `transform` property of the request options to load the body into a DOM using `cheerio.load()`. Then you can use traditional DOM selectors to traverse `body`.

In order to use [the `transform` option](https://github.com/request/request-promise#api-in-detail) on your request options object, you'll need to switch from `request` to `request-promise`. (`npm i --save request request-promise`) They function nearly identically except that `request-promise` will return an A+ promise using Bluebird where `request` uses a more traditional error first callback.

Since Cheerio uses its own implementation of jQuery you can refer to their [docs](https://cheerio.js.org) for the differences when interacting with the DOM returned.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const request = require('request-promise')

request({
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'https://google.com'
  transform: body => cheerio.load(body)
})
.then($ => {
  console.log($('p').text)
})
```

If you didn't want to switch over to `request-promise` you can still do this and make it use Promises

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const request = require('request')

const getDOMFromURI = uri => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(uri, (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err)
      }

      return resolve(cheerio.load(body))
    })
   })
}

getDOMFromURI('https://google.com').then($ => {
  console.log($('p').text)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use some other technology combination. It seems that you want to scrap website for data. Please use phantomjs or nightmare or puppeteer or any other headless browser.

A small example for you how to get first result title with puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let scrape = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=puppeteer');
    await page.waitFor(2000);

    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let title = document.querySelector('h3').innerText;

        return {
            title
        }

    });

    browser.close();
    return result;
};

scrape().then((value) => {
    console.log(value); // Success!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

from the docs, you can use a string as first argument if using GET method:

```
request('https://www.example.com', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the 
  response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
  const dom = new JSDOM(body);
  console.log(dom.window.document.querySelector("p").textContent);
});
```

see https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

You also might want to try the [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) module or [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) (which is the number 1 lib for making HTTP requests)

Once you've got the body back you may need to use [JSDOM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) or some other lib to convert the body into a document object which you can then traverse using normal JS methods or even jQuery / another DOM traversal lib.

Comment: I am currently on `http://www.google.com` but would like to get contents of `https://www.example.com/`.  I don't think this would work in that case.

Comment: sorry changed url my oopsie

Comment: But still wouldnt the above code get body of the current page you are in rather than the one passed in request url?

Comment: i dont understand why you are saying ... current page ... current page applies to a browser, nodejs doesnt have the concept of a current page ... this code would be run in nodejs outside of a browser environment and would make a GET request to example.com and return the contents of it